# python list argument in argparse module

Tags: python, command, argparse

suppose I want a command like 
`python test.py --layer 3 --sizes 100,100,100`

where `layer == len(sizes)` 
and sizes is a comma separated list

please help me with this command

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This is not a code writing service, please review [ask] and show us what you've tried.

Comment: If you specified `nargs='*'` for `--sizes` you skip the commas on input and splitting.  And `type=int` could make sure they are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use argument parser from python : https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

You have examples in the doc.

Hint for your sizes:
You can store it as a string and split it with ',' as a separator
If sizes_string is "100,100,100", you do:

```
sizes = [int(s) for s in sizes_string.split(',')]
```

Comment: how can I ensure <code> layer == len(sizes) </code> ?

Comment: You can use an assert that will stop your program if the condition is not satisfied. `assert(layer == len(sizes))`.

Comment: Test the `len(sizes)` and complain to your user.  `parse.errror` is convenient for issuing custom messages.